# The method createConnection() is undefined for the the class ConnectionFactory

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I have been trying to learn ActiveMQ and JMS. When I compile the following code I get the above exception. Although, I have attached the right jar files for JMS and ActiveMQ. Eclipse asks me to add a cast to the ConnectionFactory object when I try to create a connection (i.e. connectionFactory.createConnection()) using the ConnectionFactory object. The codes that I see everywhere on the internet are the same as I have written.

```
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.DeliveryMode;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection;
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
public class JMSProducer {
public static void main(String[] args) {
     try {
         // Create a ConnectionFactory
         ConnectionFactory connectionFactory=new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("admin", "admin",       

ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL);
         // Create a Connection

         Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
         //Error seen in above line
         connection.start();
         // Create a Session
         Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
         // Create the destination
         Destination destination = session.createQueue("testQ");
         // Create a MessageProducer from the Session to the Queue
         MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
         producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
         // Create a messages
         TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("Helloworld");
         producer.send(message);
         session.close();
         connection.close();
         System.out.println("Message sent");

     }
     catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println(e);
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sholud have done ActiveMQConnection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection(); instead of Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();. Now the code is running fine.

Comment: Not the ideal solution, connection should be generic as some client might like to use different Queues e.g.; websphere MQ instead of activeMQ.